# In an array, return all values except one

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I would like to use a formula to capitalize just the first letter of an array of words.  Sometimes the array might have just 1 word, and sometimes 2, 3, 4 or more words.  The source is dynamic, so I need my formula to be flexible. I know about `Proper(text)`, but that capitalizes every word.

For example, in cell A1 I might have the text *"aidan is a good boy,"*
or I might just have *"hi,"*
or maybe it will say, *"drive in your own lane please!"*

My formula over in B1 needs a result of *"Aidan is a good boy,"*; *"Hi,"*; or *"Drive in your own lane please!"*

I wish I could say, `B1: =Proper(index(split(M1, " "), 1)) & " " & lower(index(split(M1, " "), *everything except 1*))`, but I don't know how to fill in the `*everything except 1*` part of the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,1,UPPER(left(A1)))
```